there exists $E \subset[0, 1] $, such that $m (E) =\frac{1}{n}$ and $\int_{E} f (x) d x=\frac{a}{n} $.

Let $f \in L ([0, 1]) ,  \int_{0}^{1} f (x)  d x=a $,    Prove that for any integer $n\geq 1$, there exists $E \subset[0, 1] $,    such that $m (E) =\frac{1}{n}$ and $\int_{E} f (x)  d x=\frac{a}{n} $.

I only know for any $x\in [0,1]$, $\exists\ E_x\subset [0,1]$ such that $mE_x=x$ by continuity. What about the simultaneous intermediate value problem?

isn't your $E_x$ just $[0,x]$?

Identify $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}\cong [0,1)$ and let $g := f \ast 1_{[0,1/n)}$ be the convolution of $f$ and the indicator function.
Then $g$ is continuous with integral $a/n$, hence attains the value $a/n$ somewhere (why?!).
This proves your claim (why?!).
